# How give pattern HTML input type?

Tags: html

i validation form like this:

- cannot give comma
- cannot give minus(-)
- cannot give 0 number
- cannot give blank number
- cannot give dot(.) character

this is my code:

```
<input type="number" required min="1" step="1" pattern="^(\d+\.)?\d+$" />
```

how pattern to prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

From what I checked, it seems that it may depend on browser. With following pattern, Chrome allows numbers only, Firefox marks numbers with coma or dot as invalid and IE allows [a-z] as well.

`^([1-9]|\.|\,)+([0-9])*(\.|\,)?([0-9])*$`

I would add `onchange` event and set it up with javascript, because I can't see pattern, which will allow/disallow 0 based on first character and will remove browsers differences. 0,1 is still number.

Comment: how to prevent this type like this 000,001.

Comment: So you can, but don't want be able to type those?

Comment: `<input type="text" required="required" pattern="^((([1-9])+(\.|\,)?([0-9])*)|(0(\.|,)[0-9]+))$" />` — but this works only on FireFox. If I change type to text, Chrome allows a-z.